# How to replace with hide/show div1 with div2 and div2 with div3 using onclick() and a function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, loops, replace

i want to replace divs using onclick() in a way that they seem to rotate from the default div1 to div2 to div3 and back to div1 and over and over again.

i have with me something i have made that is working just fine but i am stuck trying to make it return to the default condition (conditions) and rotate the function show() from start to end and end to start.

this is the code i have that is working just fine but not executing the function show() from start to end and end to start

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <body>
 <div style="margin-left:30%;margin-bottom:20%;">
    <div id="div1" style="display:block">
    <h2>one</h2>
</div>
<div id="div2" style="display:none">
    <h2>two</h2>
</div>
    <div id="div3" style="display:none">
    <h2>three</h2>
</div>



    <div id="div4" style="display:block">
    <h2>one under</h2>
</div>
<div id="div5" style="display:none">
    <h2>two under</h2>
</div>
    <div id="div6" style="display:none">
    <h2>three under</h2>
</div>

<button onclick=show()>click here</button>
</div>
</body>
<script>
function show() {
    let div1 = document.querySelector('#div1');
    let div2 = document.querySelector('#div2');
let div3 = document.querySelector('#div3');
    let div4 = document.querySelector('#div4');
    let div5 = document.querySelector('#div5');
let div6 = document.querySelector('#div6');


    if (div1.style.display == "block" && div4.style.display == "block") {
        div1.style.display = "none";
        div2.style.display = "block";
       div4.style.display = "none";
        div5.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        div1.style.display = "block";
        div2.style.display = "none";
     div4.style.display = "block";
        div5.style.display = "none";
    }
   if (div2.style.display == "block" && div5.style.display == "block") {
        div2.style.display = "block";
        div3.style.display = "none";
   div5.style.display = "block";
        div6.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        div2.style.display = "none";
        div3.style.display = "block";
 div5.style.display = "none";
        div6.style.display = "block";
    }
   if (div3.style.display == "block" && div6.style.display == "block") {
        div2.style.display = "none";
       div1.style.display = "none";
        div3.style.display = "block";
       div5.style.display = "none";
       div4.style.display = "none";
        div6.style.display = "block";
  } 
 
  }
 
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simpler way is as follows

```js
const uppers = document.querySelectorAll(".upper");
const lowers = document.querySelectorAll(".lower");
let showIndex =0;
function show() {
  uppers[showIndex].style.display = lowers[showIndex].style.display = "none";
  showIndex = (showIndex + 1) % uppers.length;
  uppers[showIndex].style.display = lowers[showIndex].style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<div style="margin-left:30%;margin-bottom:20%;">
  <div id="div1" class="upper" style="display:block">
    <h2>one</h2>
  </div>
  <div id="div2" class="upper" style="display:none">
    <h2>two</h2>
  </div>
  <div id="div3" class="upper" style="display:none">
    <h2>three</h2>
  </div>



  <div id="div4" class="lower" style="display:block">
    <h2>one under</h2>
  </div>
  <div id="div5" class="lower" style="display:none">
    <h2>two under</h2>
  </div>
  <div id="div6" class="lower" style="display:none">
    <h2>three under</h2>
  </div>

  <button onclick=show()>click here</button>
</div>
```

Another way:

```js
function showNext(cls) {
  const list = document.querySelectorAll(cls);
  const curr = document.querySelector(`${cls}:not(.hide)`);
  const next = ([...list].findIndex(el => el === curr) + 1) % list.length;
  curr.classList.add('hide');
  list[next].classList.remove('hide');
}

function show() {
  showNext(".upper");
  showNext(".lower");
}
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div style="margin-left:30%;margin-bottom:20%;">
  <div id="div1" class="upper">
    <h2>one</h2>
  </div>
  <div id="div2" class="upper hide">
    <h2>two</h2>
  </div>
  <div id="div3" class="upper hide">
    <h2>three</h2>
  </div>



  <div id="div4" class="lower">
    <h2>one under</h2>
  </div>
  <div id="div5" class="lower hide">
    <h2>two under</h2>
  </div>
  <div id="div6" class="lower hide">
    <h2>three under</h2>
  </div>

  <button onclick=show()>click here</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Super smart response, exactly as intended. @Jaromanda X

Answer (score -1):

This is very old school code using pure JS and document.querySelector.

My recommendation for this code is to use JQuery.

See the toggle method https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_toggle.asp

Comment: 1. jquery is not an answer unless it's in the question - 2. w3schools is hot garbage and should never be used as an answer

Comment: Use whats available. Don't reinvent the wheel. That was one location I copied.

Comment: conversely: don't load a whole library to use only one simple function in it :D

Comment: Well it was my first response on stack overflow ever :)